# Is there any way to write an arrow table to database via a JDBC connection?

Tags: jdbc, apache-arrow

Question says it all. I've done plenty of googling, but I can only find tooling for reading database queries into arrow tables, not the inverse. The closest thing I found was the TurboDC Project, [which claimed in 2017](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/06/16/turbodbc-arrow/) that

> "Arrow support will be extended to cover the reverse direction of data flow, so that Python users can quickly insert Arrow tables into relational databases."

But as far as I can tell that hasn't happened. For our use case, we would be streaming arrow tables to a java service that would then write those tables to a database connection via JDBC.

Does anyone know of a tool or approach that we could use here?